# Flux<ByteBuffer> causing exception: LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

The below function is using Flux

We are release DataBuffer dataBufferTemp, however we are unable to find function to release Flux .

We are seeing exception:

`ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected`

```
private File createFileFromDataBuffer(Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer, String fileName, int timeoutInMin) {

        File tempFile = null;
        DataBuffer dataBufferTemp = null;

        try {
            Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("xyz");
            tempFile = new File(String.valueOf(tempDir), fileName);

            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
                dataBufferTemp = DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, os)
                        .share()
                        .blockLast(Duration.ofMinutes(timeoutInMin));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error in API, ", e);
        } finally {
            if (Objects.nonNull(dataBufferTemp)) DataBufferUtils.release(dataBufferTemp);
        }
        return tempFile;

    }
```

Any suggestions to resolve this error?

We tried if (Objects.nonNull(dataBufferTemp)) DataBufferUtils.release(dataBufferTemp);
But still same error.